# How should I review no-answers?

Tags: support, review, flags, new-users, not-an-answer

Since this morning I can make reviews in SO. I got a question which is answered with a [no-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157260/157216), what should I do rather than commenting the user to ask this as a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and probably should) flag such posts with "it is not an answer".

Comment: Is flagging only for review purposes or anyone can flag any answer?

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi Anyone (with at least 15 points of rep, as per [the privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)) can flag any answer.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi once flagged as Not An Answer, the post will arrive to the "Low Quality" review queue. From in there, you can vote to delete the answer.